# Aline Non fixed-pitch Font text in a text box

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to Aline to tab, **non-fixed-pitch** font text in a textbox.

```
TextBox1.AppendText("Sample text line" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "(100)" & vbNewLine)
TextBox1.AppendText("Sample text line Sample text line" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "(150)" & vbNewLine)
TextBox1.AppendText("Sample text line" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "(200)" & vbNewLine)
```

[image]

I want to aline to two columns those texts using tab char. Can not hardcode `vbTab` for each line because of texts are dynamically changing.

Comment: I assume that you mean "align". Maybe, if you want columns, you should use a control with columns, like a `DataGridView` or a `ListView`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney or maybe a Richtextbox with a `SelectionTabs`? I just found it

Comment: With a TextBox, you can send an [`EM_SETTABSTOPS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-settabstops) message. You need to measure each string of each column (with `TextRenderer.MeasureText`), determine which is the longest, multiply by `1.66` these measures (since, of course, internally, the Tab measure is expressed in `Display Units` - which is itself an *average* - not in Pixels :) to set an array of integers representing the new Tab Stops. I'ld use a ListView.

Comment: @Razi, not familiar with that property. I think I've learned something new.

Comment: Using `SelectionTabs` also means that you have to measure the strings. Unless you eyeball it. But changing the Font will also change the string sizes and those values express fixed positions...